# Right-to-left and/or up-to-bottom text in html/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, right-to-left

How can I make a right-to-left and up-to-bottom textfield for user input in a browser? Are there any native ways to do it? Or maybe workarounds?

(Up-to-bottom could be like Japanese, or the hieroglyphs.)

Comment: Right to left: `<textarea dir="rtl"></textarea>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RTL text field, you can use the HTML `dir` attribute (like Šime Vidas has already mentioned) or the with `dir="RTL"` `direction` attribute in CSS with `direction: rtl`. You can use these properties on most visual HTML elements, not just on text fields.

As for top-to-bottom direction, there's no easy standard method that I am aware of, but that's OK, since Japanese web pages rarely use vertical text that's not embedded in images or Flash objects, and I've never seen any site using vertical input. In fact, vertical input in Japanese computers is rare extremely rare even outside of HTML, and is usually found only in WSIWYG editors (such as Word Processors) that produce printed vertical text.

Answer (score 1):

There's also an automatic javascript that flips ltr to rtl automatically:
https://github.com/urigoren/RTLjs