# jQuery: how to get proper scrollRight value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a function which relies on the value of scrollLeft. Now, I need have this function work in right to left direction( arabic ), so I need to figure out how to get the proper scrollRight value. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Find the width of the page and subtract it from `scrollLeft()`'s value.

```
var left = $('html').scrollLeft();
var screenSize = 1024; //find width of screen / viewport. google.
var right = screensize - left;
```

Comment: the values of scrollLeft in rtl direction differ between IE and other major browsers as well. How to handle that?

Comment: put in conditional statements when dealing with different browsers?

Comment: Is there a generic solution to this issue? so I dont have to be browser specific

Comment: google can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761627/right-to-left-and-or-up-to-bottom-text-in-html-js